# integrate LightScribe functionality with c# application

Tags: c#

hope you guys could share some light with me..are you guys aware of lightscribe? i have the sdk document and am tasked to integrate LightScribe functionality with c#.can anyone of you guide me or mayb have some examples to show me?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the lightscribe api myself. But it appears to be a C++ API, what you will need to do is write a C# wrapper around it (using p/invoke)

A quick google search also turns up [this wrapper library](http://cdburnerxp.se/code) that someone has already done, have a look at the source in that and you will see the techniques used.

Comment: hi Tim, thk u for yr reply..i have seen this b4 and is able to execute it with no errors but i jus do not seem to be able to make it work..do u ahve any idea?